# $routeProvider not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to work on Angular.js tutorials. But I guess I am not doing routing correctly. I have followed documentation correctly but when I click the hyperlink, angular doesn't route to specified html. Please help me out here. I am new to Angular. Thanks in advance.

Here is my index.html head

```
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
      <script src="/js/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="/app.js"></script>
      <title>FSE</title>
</head>
```

my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('StockExchange',["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",{
            templateUrl:'/views/login.html',
            controller: 'myctrl'
    });
});

app.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.model= {
            msg:"Route Worked"
    }
});
```

and login.html

```
<h1>login</h1>
```

I have an element in my index.html where I am defining links as follows

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
     <li><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try using `#/route_name` in your `href`.

Comment: 1- your route should be like this `#/route_name`

2- define all routes in app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. I figured out that I was missing

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

directive where the routes render the html.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when("/",{ //you defined your route with "/"
        templateUrl:'/views/index.html',
        controller: 'myctrl'
   }).when("/login",{ //you defined your route with "login"
        templateUrl:'/views/login.html',
        controller: 'myctrl'
   }).when("/signup",{ //you defined your route with "signup"
        templateUrl:'/views/signup.html',
        controller: 'myctrl'
   });
});
```

so in your href should call

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
     <li><a href="#/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. But I figured out that I was making a far more silly mistake. I didn't include <ng-view></ng-view> tag where the html should render.